# can i have multiple media queries for size of rows in grid-auto-rows?

Tags: css, media-queries, css-grid

i'm building a website in grid and i would like to be able to define the height of rows at several break points (browser sizes), but so far i'm only able to define two.

this is the default:

```
.container {
  margin: 0 0;
  max-width: 100%;
  padding: 0 7%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(100px, 1fr) ) ;
  grid-auto-rows: 500px;
  row-gap: 50px;
}
```

and here are media queries:

```
@media(max-width: 500px) {
  .container {
    grid-auto-rows: 300px;
  }
}

@media(max-width: 720px) {
/*.container {
    grid-auto-rows: 400px;
  }*/
}
```

where if I uncomment the second media query, the height will be 400px on all browsers with a max-width of 720px, including those with a width below 500px.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When doing media queries, you either need to:

1. Make them **mobile-first** — your base rule contains the mobile (narrow) styles, then add media queries for **(min-width)** in **increasing** order of width.
2. Make them **desktop-first** — your base rule contains the desktop (wide) styles, then add media queries for **(max-width)** in **decreasing** order of width.

You appear to be taking approach two, but you need to rearrange your media queries so that they are in **decreasing** order of width. Your 720 rule needs to be **before** your 500 rule.

Comment: thank you! now it's working. i understand now, since all media queries have same priority, the one written after will take the priority.

Comment: glad this was useful. if you are happy to reward me for my efforts to help you, please mark this answer as the accepted answer. that will award me reputation points. cheers.

Comment: is that the mark you needed?